# Error adding foreign keys in many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

having two tables : "personnes"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personnes(
id      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nom      VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and "listadresses"

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS listadresses(
id      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
adresse VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

i'm unable to add  a foreign key for  each column based on  the primary key of  the children tables to reproduce a many to many  relation, how could i achieve this behaviour

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS liaisons(
id_nom  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
id_adresse INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT fk_nom FOREIGN KEY(id_nom) REFERENCES personnes(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_adresse FOREIGN KEY(id_adresse) REFERENCES listeadresses(id),
PRIMARY KEY(id_nom,id_adresse)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

instead i got  error code 1215. cannot add foreign key constraint, thanks in advance for any insight !

Comment: I notice you are using `NOT EXISTS`; are you sure the current versions of the referenced tables have those definitions?

Comment: i need the primary keys on both children in order to get the Auto Increment  property  for that  column , also  if not added i cannot guarantee that there is only one id number  per line table .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem :)

Instead of:

```
REFERENCES listeadresses(id),
```

try

```
REFERENCES listadresses(id),
```

It can't add the foreign key, as obviously **listeadresses** doesn't exist, but **listadresses** does.

Comment: you're right  thanks, i didn't notice it  , it solved  my issue .